# get class selected option in datalist

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

code:

```
<input type="text" id="buyer_name" list="names" v-model="order.name" class="form-control">
<datalist id="names">
    <option v-for="buyer in buyers" :value="buyer.name" :class="buyer.id"></option>
</datalist>
```

How to get class of selected option?

Comment: What is `datalist`? How is the selected option determined/communicated?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that :)

Comment: Not long ago, I, too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    order:{
      name: null
    },
    buyers:[{name: "buyer one", id: 1},{name: "buyer two", id: 2}]
  },
  computed:{
    selectedClass(){
      const buyer = this.buyers.find(b => b.name === this.order.name)
      if (buyer)
        return buyer.id
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" id="buyer_name" list="names" v-model="order.name" class="form-control">
  <datalist id="names">
      <option v-for="buyer in buyers" :value="buyer.name" :class="buyer.id"></option>
  </datalist>
  
  {{selectedClass}}
</div>
```

Comment: This should work, but there is have a little defect. This code does not work correctly in the case of identical names

Comment: @OlegShleif I don't think you have a choice. There is no connection to the input other than the value.

Comment: Well, thank you, we will look for another solution then.